# Setting up a secure LAN within an existing not owned LAN

Tags: vlan, lan

Shown in the figure is a univercity network. The devices inside the red boxes are owned by the laboraroty in which I am working. I want to setup a secure subnet for all devices that are within the red boxes. (Each red box is a seperate room) The problem is that I don't have any access in the devices that are not inside red boxes. Currently internet access and DHCP services are provided by the university server. I want to provide DHCP and static IPs to all the machines inside the boxes and make them be in their own secure LAN within the univercity LAN (I don't want the devices to be visible outside the new LAN)[image]. Can I do this using the windows 2019 server?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You need to set up a firewall between your network and the university network, then you can do whatever you want on your network with no interference from the university network.

Comment: "_Working with the univercity IT department is not an option._" Then, unfortunately, your question is really off-topic here for a couple of reasons.

Answer (score 2):

What you're really looking for is a *firewall*: separating your trusted devices from the untrusted rest.

Using a routing firewall allows you to separate all layer-2 traffic, and control what is permitted across the router and what is not.

It's best to work out the details with the university's IT department. If the upstream network won't recognize/support your router and separate network, you need to use NAT: translate your "private" IP addresses to one (or possibly more) recognized "public" address(es) and back.

VLANs just allow you to use a single switch (structure) for both "private" and public" sides while keeping the logically separate. Without a router and firewall you'd just have two networks, without any communication.

**EDIT**: Sorry, I hadn't got the room-interconnection-isn't-trusted bit yet. Basically, there are three approaches.

1. Use four transparent firewalls to permit traffic into each room only from one of your other rooms by IP address. Also, permit traffic to the Internet. This approach is the least secure as externals could spoof internal IP addresses.
2. If you've got the cooperation of the IT department, you can set up your own VLAN that nobody interferes with. Connect that VLAN to the university net via firewall. The loophole on this one is that you need to trust the IT team, as they could configure the VLAN without your knowledge.
3. Without cooperation of IT, you set up VPN links - effectively an overlay network. Each room needs a VPN router, tunneling your trusted traffic over untrusted territory. This approach is watertight. Also, you'll need a firewall to control traffic with the university net.

**Disclaimer**: Anything you do without consent or proper authorization from the right people needs to be permitted within the university's security policies. Violating those could make you face serious consequences.

Comment: How would the firewall help? The trusted devices are located in different physical rooms and each room is connected with  the others with infrastracture that I cannot control. Also the univercity has a central firewall for protection against external threts

Comment: I actually didn't get that part - I've update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may be aware of Windows Server's **Internet Connection Sharing** feature -- which is *not a substitute* for the switches and wireless access points in your topology diagram, or having separate VLAN(s) on the university's equipment.

I suggest working with your Uni's I.T. department to plan an appropriate installation for your needs.  You will need to cooperate with them to configure an uplink at some point, anyway; and at that time, they may want to review & approve your firewall choice, if not your overall design.  That's usually so they can help you when you need it, more so than to exercise unnecessary control over users.  This means they may also strongly suggest you use a firewall made by a preferred vendor; and that's likely to be to your advantage if you do need help.

Comment: Working with the univercity IT department is not an option. Anytime we ask for their help they want to include everything under their active directory, this means a ton of restrictions for us. If all devices where at the same room I could easily solve the problem by installing two network cards in our server PC and pass all trafic through the server. The problem is that there is equipment in other rooms that cannot be physically connect to the server directly.

Comment: Maybe you can pare down your needs slightly.  If you could leave the printers on the normal Uni network, and just use VPN software on all your computers to connect back to your server, would that satisfy all your needs?  Or is the real goal to enable users affiliated with your lab to login to computers and access the Uni network (e.g. pass 802.1X authentication to use ethernet/wireless) even if those users are not already enrolled in the University's authentication system?

Comment: Using VPN woudn't be enough. To further explain: the Univercity has 2 connection options: "Private" through Uni's AD and "public" both of these options use the same network infrastracture. So what I want is to keep our devices to the "public" network but have them in our AD so that we can control access to our printers, check our trafic, enable features like "wake on LAN" e.t.c. and have shared folders and access to storage space on the server. We just want to "group" the LAB's devices while keeping them on saperate rooms and keeping them out of Uni's AD

Comment: Well, VPNs would accomplish most of your goals.  To get to "all" goals accomplished, you are going to need your own switches, wireless access points (and controller, if you need roaming), and either cabling between floors/rooms, or tunneling over the Uni network (which may not work, depending on Uni's restrictions on that "Public" network.)  It's far more involved than one Windows Server.